# Bash function variables persist between calls

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/sh/

function test() {
       echo BEFORE var1 $var1
       echo BEFORE var1 $var1

       var1=$1
       var2=$2

       echo AFTER var1 $var1
       echo AFTER var1 $var1
}

test 1 2
test 3 4
```

Result:

```
BEFORE var1
BEFORE var2
AFTER var1 1
AFTER var2 2
BEFORE var1 1
BEFORE var2 2
AFTER var1 3
AFTER var2 4
```

Why does var1 and var2 keep the values from the first time the function is called when the second time the function is called? How do I get the variables to clear every time?

Comment: The code you posted and the output cannot have been generated by the same script. Please update your post, so that both match.

Comment: The shebang cannot end in a `/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `local` keyword.

Try

```
function test() {
       local var1
       local var2
       echo BEFORE var1 $var1
       echo BEFORE var1 $var1

       var1=$1
       var2=$2

       echo AFTER var1 $var1
       echo AFTER var1 $var1
}
```

Comment: @terence, note that `local` is a bash command, so change your shebang to `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: `function` is also a `bash` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach:

```
test () (
    echo "BEFORE var1 $var1"
    echo "BEFORE var2 $var2"

    var1="$1"
    var2="$2"

    echo "AFTER var1 $var1"
    echo "AFTER var2 $var2"
)
```

Values of `var1` and `var2` that exist outside the function will be seen for the "BEFORE" lines, but the changes shown in the "AFTER" lines will be local to the function. This is an all-or-none approach; you cannot change global variables inside the subshell created by the function, but this doesn't require any non-POSIX features.